# How to continuously fetch data from websites like Stock exchange and send it to azure event hub using python?

Tags: python, websocket, rabbitmq, azure-eventhub, azure-eventgrid

I'm trying to do real-time streaming and processing with an azure event hub and azure stream analytics for NSE(National stock exchange)
For that first, I need to get the data in real-time and to send the data to the event hub.
How to get the get continuous in real-time?
How to send data asynchronously to the event hub, If I'm getting data from the multiple sources in real?
How to process that asynchronous data with Azure stream analytics?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

First of all your question has 10 problems to solve. Solve only one problem at a time.

> For that first, I need to get the data in real-time and to send the data to the event hub.

Yes first make a small POC Application which can retrieve data based on your needs.

Forget **real-time**, just retrieve the data and try to send it to EventHub First.

You can quickstart with `python sdk` from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-python-get-started-send)

> How to process that asynchronous data with Azure stream analytics?

Azure Stream Analytics is a whole different topic. You can refer its docs [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/stream-analytics/)

I have answered this since i can see you are a newbie here and your question will get downvoted. Take it slow. Solve one problem at a time